12V rated PCB works when connected to power with AC-DC convertor but not on 12V battery
I am trying to run a pretty powerful LED driver with PWM dimming (1 LED only but 1.25 A current) and I am using LM3421.
For a test I need to power the led driver PCB with a battery. Got a few kinds of NiMH: 7.2V, 12V sub-C cell so current should not be a problem. I am using a normal ON-OFF switch to power the PCB. AND the problems started.
What I observed so far:

connecting the AC-DC (100VAC-12VDC) directly to the plug - all works correctly;
adding the ON-OFF switch between the AC-DC and PCB - nothing works (a short blink of the LED)
connected 7.2V battery through the switch - short blink at the start only; I tried switching on and off the PCB and once made it work as expected
connected 12V battery - no light, short blink when turned off (much weaker than the 7.2V blink)

The test with AC-DC and switch added/removed points me into the direction of voltage spikes or similar issue due to the switch. I guess that because of the transformer, the AC-DC has smooth transient with no or limited spikes at the start, but using a switch to power On/OFF is a disaster... Any experience/opinions are appreciated. I guess my led driver design is also messed up, but works correctly on 12V AC-DC (used a PD with oscilloscope and confirmed LED blinking at correct PWM frequency). I wonder if adding TVS diode at the input will change the situation.
Edit: Schematic (R5 re-soldered to 33K)


It's probably due to a voltage spike at turn-on. But that can't exceed double the input voltage, ie 24V, and your chip is rated to 75V, so it should be safe. Question is, why does it remain off? Perhaps the resistor divider on the OVP pin has the wrong values... can you show a schematic?

Thank you for the comment! I am also scared I made a mistake there. I use the Buck schematic in the datasheet (p. 59) and the values on p. 60. So, OVP values are 21.5K and 499K. Should not shut down up to 55V if I calculate correctly. The main change I made is on the DIMn pin UVLO. I changed RUV1 value from 11.5K to 33K to allow 5V turn on instead of 15V. I need only one LED so decided to reduce the voltage values... I guess this is wrong. Also, for some reason I decreased the L1 value to 3.3uH. It says not to mount Co, but I added 3.3uF there, probably based on some text in the datasheet.

OK, can you post the schematic exactly as it is on your board? 'cause I don't see a page 60 ;)

Yes, sorry. I added the schematic. Probably a bit messy....

Weird, it's hard to read but I don't see anything wrong with it. So, divide and conquer: when it should be on but remains off, is it switching? If yes, maybe the PMOS is conducting when it shouldn't. If it's not switching, check voltage on all pins that can disable it (UVLO, OVP, EN, VCC, RPD...)
